# read a very big single line txt file and split it

Tags: c#, java, python

I have the following problem:
I have a file which is nearly 500mb big. Its text, all in one line. The text is seperated with a virtual line ending, its called ROW_DEL and is in the text like this:

```
this is a line ROW_DEL and this is a line
```

now I need to make the following, I want to split this file into its lines so I get a file like this:

```
this is a line
and this is a line
```

the problem, even if I open it with the windows text editor, it breakes because the file is to big.

Is it possible to split this file like I mentioned with C#, Java or Python? Whats would be the best soultion to dont overkill my cpu.

Comment: can't you use `sed` or any scripting tools?

Comment: Why do you call ROW_DEL a virtual ending ? Is ROW_DEL a succession of characters in the file or not ? Your problem is easy to solve, I think, but this point perplexes me.

Comment: You could try reading the file in fixed size blocks, check out the documentation on `read` from the StreamReader docs (http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/stream-reader-objects.html)

Comment: ROW_DEL is a succession of characters in the file.

Comment: My vote for sed: there are ports for windows if needed.

Comment: what is sed and what does it do?

Comment: @gurehbgui [sed man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed).

Comment: Hello. I posted an answer in Python to your problem. Please, take a look on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually 500mb of text is not that big, it's just that notepad sucks.  You probably don't have sed available since you're on windows but at least try naive solution in python, I think it will work fine:

```
import os
with open('infile.txt') as f_in, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f_out:
  f_out.write(f_in.read().replace('ROW_DEL ', os.linesep))
```

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was downvoted it actually works instantly and answers the question. Maybe `'ROW_DEL '` should be `' ROW_DEL '`

Comment: I think your answer could be fatal when reading bigger files. You could go with a much more time consuming but safer method if you read by char to fill a vector of length equal to that of the searched substring, pop front, push back and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Read this file in chunks, for example use [`StreamReader.ReadBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.streamreader.readblock.aspx) in c#. You can set the maximum number of characters to read there.

For each readed chunk you can replace `ROW_DEL` to `\r\n` and append it to new file.

Just remember to increase current index by the number of character you just read.

Comment: What if ROW_DEL is splitted into two chunks?

Comment: Right.. in this case just check if your chunk last letters are part of `ROW_DEL` and read few more characters if needed. You have full control over how much you want to read so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.
Easy in the principle (ŁukaszW.pl gave it) but not so easy to code if one wants to take care of peculiar cases (which ŁukaszW.pl did not).

The peculiar cases are when the separator ROW_DEL is splitted in two of the read chunks (as I4V pointed out), and even more subtlely if there are two contiguous ROW_DEL of which the second is splitted in two read chunks.

Since ROW_DEL is longer than any of the possible newlines (`'\r'`, `'\n'`, `'\r\n'`) , it can be replaced in place in the file by the newline used by the OS. That's why I choosed to rewrite the file in itself.
For that I use mode `'r+'`, it doesn't create a new file.
It's also absolutely mandatory to use a binary mode `'b'`.

The principle is to read a chunk (in real life its size will be 262144 for example) and **x** additional characters, wher **x** is the length of the separator -1.
And then to examine if the separator is present in the end of the chunk + the x characters.
Accoridng if it is present or not, the chunk is shortened or not before the transformation of the ROW_DEL is performed, and rewritten in place.

The nude code is:

```
text = ('The hospital roommate of a man infected ROW_DEL'
        'with novel coronavirus (NCoV)ROW_DEL'
        '—a SARS-related virus first identified ROW_DELROW_DEL'
        'last year and already linked to 18 deaths—ROW_DEL'
        'has contracted the illness himself, ROW_DEL'
        'intensifying concerns about the ROW_DEL'
        "virus's ability to spread ROW_DEL"
        'from person to person.')

with open('eessaa.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(text)

with open('eessaa.txt','rb') as f:
    ch = f.read()
    print ch.replace('ROW_DEL','ROW_DEL\n')
    print '\nlength of the text : %d chars\n' % len(text)

#==========================================

from os.path import getsize
from os import fsync,linesep

def rewrite(whichfile,sep,chunk_length,OSeol=linesep):
    if chunk_length<len(sep):
        print 'Length of second argument, %d , is '\
              'the minimum value for the third argument'\
              % len(sep)
        return

    x = len(sep)-1
    x2 = 2*x
    file_length = getsize(whichfile)
    with open(whichfile,'rb+') as fR,\
         open(whichfile,'rb+') as fW:
        while True:
            chunk = fR.read(chunk_length)
            pch = fR.tell()
            twelve = chunk[-x:] + fR.read(x)
            ptw = fR.tell()

            if sep in twelve:
                pt = twelve.find(sep)
                m = ("\n   !! %r is "
                     "at position %d in twelve !!" % (sep,pt))
                y = chunk[0:-x+pt].replace(sep,OSeol)
            else:
                pt = x
                m = ''
                y = chunk.replace(sep,OSeol)

            pos = fW.tell()
            fW.write(y)
            fW.flush()
            fsync(fW.fileno())

            if fR.tell()<file_length:
                fR.seek(-x2+pt,1)
            else:
                fW.truncate()
                break

rewrite('eessaa.txt','ROW_DEL',14)

with open('eessaa.txt','rb') as f:
    ch = f.read()
    print '\n'.join(repr(line)[1:-1] for line in ch.splitlines(1))
    print '\nlength of the text : %d chars\n' % len(ch)
```

To follow the execution, here's another code that prints messages all along:

```
text = ('The hospital roommate of a man infected ROW_DEL'
        'with novel coronavirus (NCoV)ROW_DEL'
        '—a SARS-related virus first identified ROW_DELROW_DEL'
        'last year and already linked to 18 deaths—ROW_DEL'
        'has contracted the illness himself, ROW_DEL'
        'intensifying concerns about the ROW_DEL'
        "virus's ability to spread ROW_DEL"
        'from person to person.')

with open('eessaa.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(text)

with open('eessaa.txt','rb') as f:
    ch = f.read()
    print ch.replace('ROW_DEL','ROW_DEL\n')
    print '\nlength of the text : %d chars\n' % len(text)

#==========================================

from os.path import getsize
from os import fsync,linesep

def rewrite(whichfile,sep,chunk_length,OSeol=linesep):
    if chunk_length<len(sep):
        print 'Length of second argument, %d , is '\
              'the minimum value for the third argument'\
              % len(sep)
        return

    x = len(sep)-1
    x2 = 2*x
    file_length = getsize(whichfile)
    with open(whichfile,'rb+') as fR,\
         open(whichfile,'rb+') as fW:
        while True:
            chunk = fR.read(chunk_length)
            pch = fR.tell()
            twelve = chunk[-x:] + fR.read(x)
            ptw = fR.tell()

            if sep in twelve:
                pt = twelve.find(sep)
                m = ("\n   !! %r is "
                     "at position %d in twelve !!" % (sep,pt))
                y = chunk[0:-x+pt].replace(sep,OSeol)
            else:
                pt = x
                m = ''
                y = chunk.replace(sep,OSeol)
            print ('chunk  == %r   %d chars\n'
                   ' -> fR now at position  %d\n'
                   'twelve == %r   %d chars   %s\n'
                   ' -> fR now at position  %d'
                   % (chunk ,len(chunk),      pch,
                      twelve,len(twelve),m,   ptw) )

            pos = fW.tell()
            fW.write(y)
            fW.flush()
            fsync(fW.fileno())
            print ('          %r   %d long\n'
                   ' has been written from position %d\n'
                   ' => fW now at position  %d'
                   % (y,len(y),pos,fW.tell()))

            if fR.tell()<file_length:
                fR.seek(-x2+pt,1)
                print ' -> fR moved %d characters back to position %d'\
                       % (x2-pt,fR.tell())
            else:
                print (" => fR is at position %d == file's size\n"
                       '    File has thoroughly been read'
                       % fR.tell())
                fW.truncate()
                break

            raw_input('\npress any key to continue')


rewrite('eessaa.txt','ROW_DEL',14)

with open('eessaa.txt','rb') as f:
    ch = f.read()
    print '\n'.join(repr(line)[1:-1] for line in ch.splitlines(1))
    print '\nlength of the text : %d chars\n' % len(ch)
```

There's some subtlety in the treatment of the ends of the chunks in order to detect if ROW_DEL straddles on two chunks and if there are two ROW_DEL contiguous. That's why I took a long time to post my solution: I finally was obliged to write `fR.seek(-x2+pt,1)` and not only `fR.seek(-2*x,1)` or `fR.seek(-x,1)` according if **sep** is straddling or not (2*x is x2 in the code, with ROW_DEL x and x2 are 6 and 12). Anybody interested by this point will examine it by changing the codes in the sections accoridng `if 'ROW_DEL' is in twelve` or not.