# Modify file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have files that contains the following lines:

```
info face="asd" size=49 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=0,0
common lineHeight=52 base=43 scaleW=128 scaleH=128 pages=1 packed=0
page id=0 file="asd.png"
chars count=9
char id=32 x=58 y=82 width=0 height=0 xoffset=0 yoffset=40 xadvance=9 page=0 chnl=0
char id=179 x=34 y=42 width=28 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=26 page=0 chnl=0
char id=181 x=94 y=2 width=28 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=26 page=0 chnl=0
char id=183 x=2 y=42 width=30 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=27 page=0 chnl=0
char id=185 x=2 y=2 width=30 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=27 page=0 chnl=0
char id=187 x=64 y=2 width=28 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=26 page=0 chnl=0
char id=189 x=34 y=2 width=28 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=26 page=0 chnl=0
char id=191 x=34 y=82 width=22 height=36 xoffset=2 yoffset=8 xadvance=18 page=0 chnl=0
char id=193 x=2 y=82 width=28 height=38 xoffset=2 yoffset=6 xadvance=26 page=0 chnl=0
kernings count=0
```

I need to find the `id` value, then based on simple condition modify(add/subtract some number from the value) that number and write file back. My attempt is:

```
input = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in input:
```

here I am thinking to capture 3 parts of line `char id=`, value and the rest of line. Then modify value and create new string. But I doubt it's effective way in Python. Also I'm not sure if there is a way to work on same file instead of creating new file, deleting old and renaming back to old name in order to modify file content.

Comment: _" I'm not sure if there is a way to work on same file instead of creating new file, deleting old and renaming back to old name"_ Yes, there is, but the condition is that every part of string that must be replaced must be longer or of same length than the replacement one. An example of this way to process here: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16591889/551449) The key is to open the file in mode ``'rb+'``. But the example I give is rather complex because in this file it was possible that the pattern to be replaced would be contiguously repeated. In your case, it wouldn't be the case, I presume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll *have* to replace the file (so write to a temporary file). However, the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) makes this easy for you:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('char id='):
        _, id_, rest = line.split(None, 2)
        id_ = int(id_.split('=')[1])
        id_ += 1  # adjust as needed
        line = 'char id={} {}'.format(id_, rest)

    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This example simply increments the `id` value by 1, you can adjust the code to do whatever you want with the `id_` integer.

By specifying `inplace=True`, the `fileinput` module will move the original file to a backup, capture anything you write to `stdout`, and write it to original file location instead.

Comment: I got invalid syntax on `id_`. Is this some reserved keyword?

Comment: @Pablo: No, I forgot to remove some text (`int(`)  on the previous line as I edited the answer. Fixed.

Comment: works like a charm, just had to .close stream otherwise the file was empty. thanks!